# How can I get username in groups using groupid?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to make some kind of hierarchy group tree.
For making it, I refer to google admin sdk reference.

but I encountered 1 problem using under code.

```
Service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

groupResults = Service.members().list(groupKey='groupsmail@test.com').execute()

groups = groupResults.get('members', [])
# users = groupResults.get('users', [])

if not groups:
    print('No users in the domain.')
else:
    for group in groups:
        if(group.get('type') == 'USER'):
            email = group.get('email')
            users = Service.users().get(userKey=email).execute()
            print(email, users.get('name').get('fullName'))
```

this output is

1@test.com user1name
2@test.com user2name
....

but, it's too slow to use.
So, I wonder how can get username list using groups id?

I did looking for references but couldn't find it.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve in a single call the members list.

Doing a GET request to `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members`

where `groupKey` is the email address of the group OR the groupId. You can optionally filter results by role too.

### References:

[Get all members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-roup-members#get_all_members)